# Why does instabot in flask throw an error about wsgi?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Hello when i try to post on instagram flask doesn't let me do it and i have no idea why. I tested the instagram bot's library and it works but in flask it doesn't want to. Can someone help me solve this problem?

Python gives me this error:

```
2021-09-11 12:23:38,852 - INFO - Instabot version: 0.117.0 Started
2021-09-11 12:23:38,853 - INFO - Not yet logged in starting: PRE-LOGIN FLOW!
2021-09-11 12:23:41,559 - INFO - Logged-in successfully as 'user'!
2021-09-11 12:23:41,559 - INFO - LOGIN FLOW! Just logged-in: True
127.0.0.1 - - [11/Sep/2021 12:23:53] "POST /submit HTTP/1.1" 500 -
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\adamk\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\Lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 2088, in __call__
    return self.wsgi_app(environ, start_response)
  File "C:\Users\adamk\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\Lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 2073, in wsgi_app
    response = self.handle_exception(e)
  File "C:\Users\adamk\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\Lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 2070, in wsgi_app
    response = self.full_dispatch_request()
  File "C:\Users\adamk\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\Lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1515, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.handle_user_exception(e)
  File "C:\Users\adamk\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\Lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1513, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.dispatch_request()
  File "C:\Users\adamk\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\Lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1499, in dispatch_request
    return self.ensure_sync(self.view_functions[rule.endpoint])(**req.view_args)
  File "D:\Programowanie\spotted\app.py", line 43, in submit
    bot.login(username="user", password="password")
  File "C:\Users\adamk\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\Lib\site-packages\instabot\bot\bot.py", line 450, in login
    signal.signal(signal.SIGTERM, self.print_counters)
  File "C:\Users\adamk\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\Lib\signal.py", line 47, in signal
    handler = _signal.signal(_enum_to_int(signalnum), _enum_to_int(handler))
ValueError: signal only works in main thread of the main interpreter
127.0.0.1 - - [11/Sep/2021 12:23:53] "GET /submit?__debugger__=yes&cmd=resource&f=debugger.js HTTP/1.1" 200 -
127.0.0.1 - - [11/Sep/2021 12:23:53] "GET /submit?__debugger__=yes&cmd=resource&f=style.css HTTP/1.1" 200 -
127.0.0.1 - - [11/Sep/2021 12:23:54] "GET /submit?__debugger__=yes&cmd=resource&f=console.png HTTP/1.1" 200 -
127.0.0.1 - - [11/Sep/2021 12:23:54] "GET /submit?__debugger__=yes&cmd=resource&f=ubuntu.ttf HTTP/1.1" 200 -
```

Here's my code:

```
@app.route('/submit', methods=['POST', 'GET'])
def submit():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        message = request.form['text']
        message = message.replace('\r', '')
        if message.rstrip() == '':
            return render_template('index.html', message='You cannot send an empty message!')

        font = ImageFont.truetype("OpenSans-Regular.ttf", 40)

        img = Image.open('image.jpg')

        draw = ImageDraw.Draw(img)
        draw.text((170, 280), message.rstrip(), (0, 0, 0), font=font)

        i = 0
        while os.path.exists(f'image-output-{i}.jpeg'):
            i += 1

        img.save(f'image-output-{i}.jpg')

        cookie_del = glob.glob("config/*cookie.json")
        os.remove(cookie_del[0])
        bot = Bot()
        bot.login(username="user", password="password")
        bot.upload_photo('image.jpg', caption='')
        return render_template('sent.html')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not a problem with `flask` but rather `instabot`. You can see in the traceback:

```
File "D:\Programowanie\spotted\app.py", line 43, in submit
```

Which is the only part of the traceback that actually references your own code. The `login` method is [here](https://github.com/ohld/igbot/blob/d68b55015322898c3842c92dcc5989581043252e/instabot/bot/bot.py#L436). From the docstring, you'll see:

> if login function is run threaded, for example in scheduled job,
> signal will fail because it 'only works in main thread'.
> In this case, you may want to call login(is_threaded=True).

`flask` uses thread-local objects so you need to add the argument suggested.